# Sharable link of the React Router path in email

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using 'react-router-dom' and have one of the route like this.

```
                    <Route path="/yourapp/infoFillUp/:emailAddr" component={SendInfo} />
```

If I give a link somewhere inside my application then it works fine. But I need to distribute this link to the external audience in email. They should be able to click on it and land on the page to fill more information.

When I click on the link from outside of the application, it gives an error that page not found.

Tried Redirect of the 'react-router-dom' but no luck. Not sure, what is the way to fix this.

Comment: you need to set up a server to send the same index file on these routes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But not sure what is the way to do this. Trying my hands on all these for the first time.

Comment: it depends on what server are you using. Most hosting providers make this very easy. Try to search in your providers docs for static-site redirects.